# How to append items to various lists without iterating from the beginning?

Tags: python, nested-for-loop

I am trying to fill my variable 'test' with items from 'mylist'. If the condition `totaltime < 6` is met, the iteration starts over at mylist[0], so the lists never get beyond '3' (2nd indice in mylist). However, I want that if the condition is met, then the iteration will continue filling the second list. How can I ensure that my iteration continues where it left off? so that the result is the following:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
time = [2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 6, 5, 1]

test = [[], [], [], []]
```

I tried the following

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
time = [2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 6, 5, 1]

test = [[], [], [], []]

totaltime = 0

for i in range(len(test)):
    for jobs in range(len(mylist)):
        if totaltime < 6:
            test[i].append(mylist[jobs])
            totaltime += time[jobs]
    totaltime = 0

print(test)
```

with the result:

`[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

`[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

`[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

However, I want my iteration not to start over again, as stated above. As a result, the desired result should be the following:

```
test = [1, 2, 3], [4,5], [6], [7, 8]
```

Comment: i really don't understand the criteria for the resulting list you want.

Comment: why is `3` included in `test[0]` **and** in `test[1]`? Why is `6` nowhere?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 6 is nowhere because the corresponding time (6) isn't strictly less than 6 so the if statement evaluates to false and would skip it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're confusing the mylist and time lists. the time list is the one being added to total time, so the times for 7 and 8 (5 and 1) do work. also with 3 being included twice, I believe the expected output is meant to be [1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8]

Comment: @actuallyatiger ah, yes, of course. And that makes sense (the output you describe)

Comment: why is 3 repeated in the desired? shouldnt it continue from 4 after adding 3 to the first list? anyways, you can do it with a temp list. append to temp, when condition is met append temp to test and redeclare temp = [].

Comment: @actuallyatiger wait, it's still not clear to me. The sum of the corresponding times for `1`, `2`, and `3` is `6`, so why is `3` included?

Comment: I agree that the desired result can't be understood from what is given here, and expect that the desired result is in fact *incorrect*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga because 1 and 2 are added, with a total time of 4. it then checks that this is less than 6, and since it is it'll add 3

Comment: @actuallyatiger but that would make the cumulative value 6. In the case of the lone `6`, the total_count shoulb be `0 + 6` at this point, no? Why doesn't it work the same as the third  `2`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that is a good point. i believe in that case there would also be a 6 in the output, so i think it should be [1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7, 8]

Comment: I made a typo, the desired result is that items from mylist are added to a list in test, if the totaltime <=6. However, this will result for the first list in test in [1,2,3,4]. Therefore i used totaltime < 6 instead of '<=', since totaltime of [1,2,3,4] is 11. I think maybe a temp list will do the job in getting the desired result

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are nesting the looping. I think the easiest way is just to loop over once and keep an index into `test` which you can increment when you need to. The following works:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
time = [2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 6, 5, 1]


total_time = 0
i = 0
test = [[], [], [], []]
for t, item in zip(time, mylist):
    total_time += t
    test[i].append(item)
    if total_time >= 6:
        i += 1
        total_time = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this from a functional point of view and came up with this less-obvious but perhaps easier to grok solution. Prefer juanpa's for edification, but I'd probably prefer mine for production code.

```py
def take_while_sum_lt(max_: int):
    def _inner(iterator):
        acc = []
        total = 0
        for idx, val in iterator:
            total += val
            acc.append(idx)
            if total >= max_:
                yield acc
                acc = []
                total = 0
        if acc:
            # take the rest of the iterator
            yield acc
    return _inner
```

This is an iterator that takes the zip of `mylist, time` and produces the correct result. For instance:

```py
# take_while_sum_lt defined as above

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
time = [2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 6, 5, 1]

# this produces an iterator function that takes while the sum less than 6
take_while_sum_lt_6 = take_while_sum_lt(6)

result = take_while_sum_lt_6(zip(mylist, time))
```

Comment: This could probably use a functools.wraps somewhere, but I always forget where that sucker goes and I haven't been working professionally in Python for a while. If somebody knows better where to add it (above _inner, pointing at take_while_sum_lt?) please add it :)